# Why are the weight vectors corresponding to the raising and lowering operators given by the formula $\bar{t_{1}}- \bar{t_{2}}$?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading Robinson's particle physics paper part-I which is available in the public domain
[here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3328), particularly the theory of SU(3) Lie Groups.  Page 63 of the text states that,

> Now, repeating nearly the identical argument we started with equation
> 2.42 and repeating it for all 6 non-Cartan generators, we find that in order to maintain (2.36) and (2.40) we must work with the operators
> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T^{1}\pm iT^{2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E^{1}\pm
>  iE^{2})$
>
> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T^{4}\pm iT^{5})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E^{3}\pm
>  iE^{4})$
>
> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T^{6}\pm iT^{7})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E^{5}\pm
> iE^{6})$ (2.48)
>
> The weight vectors associated with these will be, respectively,
> $\pm (\bar{t_{1}}-\bar{t_{2}})=\pm$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\pm (\bar{t_{1}}-\bar{t_{3}})=\pm$ $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$,$\pm (\bar{t_{2}}-\bar{t_{3}})=\pm$ $\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \end{bmatrix}$ (2.49)
> Here the $T^1$ and $T^2$ are the generators of the SU(3) group in it's fundamental representation, which consists of 8 matrices in total given in the page 62 of the same book, and the raising and lowering operators are constructed out of it. Now I can understand how these matrices raise the eigenstates of the Cartan generators given by the following,but fail to understand it's relation with the weight vectors and how the author obtains them in this case.
> $v_{1}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$,$v_{2}= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$,and $v_{3}= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Now my confusion is about weight vectors and root vectors, and how he gets this $\bar{t_{1}}- \bar{t_{2}}$? (also the $\bar{t_{1}}- \bar{t_{3}}$) expression to calculate the weight vectors, particularly in view of the fact that he defines the concept of weight vector in page 54 of the same paper as applicable only to Cartan operators but clearly the raising operators are not Cartan and he chooses $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ as Cartan Operators. He hasn't proved that the weight vectors can be calculated via such an expression, which is confusing me.

The paper is:

> [A Simple Introduction to Particle Physics](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0810.3328), Robinson, M., Bland, K., Cleaver, G., & Dittmann, J. (2008).

Note that I have deleted the previous version of this question, as it contained a screenshot.